# haskell logging with datetimes

Tags: haskell

I'm playing around with this writer monad logging example:

http://monads.haskell.cz/examples/example17.hs

I'm using it as a toy problem to figure out how to use a writer monad to do logging.
I'm trying to modify the program so it outputs the datetime with each line.
My initial thinking is to modify `logMsg` like this:

```
-- add a message to the log
logMsg :: String -> Writer [Entry] ()
logMsg s = do
  datetime <- getClockTime
  tell [Log 1 (datetime ++ " " ++ s)]
```

But, this doesn't compile. I think I need to insert `IO` somewhere. Where? Help!

Answer (score 1):

`Writer` is a type alias t `WriterT w Identity`, so you can create your alias with `IO` inner monad instead of `Identity`, something like:

```
type WriterIO = Writer w IO
```

And you can use IO via, for example [liftIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v%3aliftIO), e.g.:

```
-- add a message to the log
logMsg :: String -> WriterIO [Entry] ()
logMsg s = do
    datetime <- liftIO getClockTime
    tell [Log 1 (show datetime ++ " " ++ s)]
```

Comment: `type WriterIO = WriterT IO Identity` won't compile, the first parameter is the `Monoid` used for logging. You probably meant `type WriterIO w = WriterT w IO`.

Comment: OK, I also changed runWriter to runWriterT, but now it says:     Couldn't match expected type `(,) t0' with actual type `IO'
    Expected type: WriterT [Entry] ((,) t0) a0
      Actual type: WriterIO [Entry] [Packet]
    In the return type of a call of `filterAll'
    In the first argument of `runWriterT', namely
      `(filterAll rules packets)'

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is not to use IO in the writer monad itself, but let it return the log entries and then use those after runWriterT has returned.
Here's a program that sums it's arguments and also logs each of them: https://gist.github.com/zsol/4741625

Comment: I want to tag the log lines with the date =)